# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unbound_message'

Tags: python, flask, flask-restx

I got the above error when I try to import fields from `flask_restx`.

```
from flask_restx import fields
```

What is the problem. It works on my local machine but not on remote machine.

Full error trace:

```
  File "/root/.clearml/venvs-builds/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clearml/binding/import_bind.py", line 54, in __patched_import3
    mod = builtins.__org_import__(
  File "/root/.clearml/venvs-builds/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restx/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import fields, reqparse, apidoc, inputs, cors
  File "/root/.clearml/venvs-builds/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clearml/binding/import_bind.py", line 54, in __patched_import3
    mod = builtins.__org_import__(
  File "/root/.clearml/venvs-builds/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restx/fields.py", line 16, in <module>
    from flask import url_for, request
  File "/root/.clearml/venvs-builds/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clearml/binding/import_bind.py", line 54, in __patched_import3
    mod = builtins.__org_import__(
  File "/root/.clearml/venvs-builds/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import json as json
  File "/root/.clearml/venvs-builds/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clearml/binding/import_bind.py", line 54, in __patched_import3
    mod = builtins.__org_import__(
  File "/root/.clearml/venvs-builds/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ..globals import current_app
  File "/root/.clearml/venvs-builds/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clearml/binding/import_bind.py", line 54, in __patched_import3
    mod = builtins.__org_import__(
  File "/root/.clearml/venvs-builds/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 56, in <module>
    app_ctx: "AppContext" = LocalProxy(  # type: ignore[assignment]
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unbound_message'
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback, please?

Comment: I added the full error.

Comment: What version of flask-restx are you using?

Comment: flask-restx==0.5.1

Answer (score 19):

I added *flask==2.1.3* to my requirements and it worked. I think this is a problem with the currently lastest versions of flask/

Answer (score 4):

I had an older version of Werkzeug in my requirements.txt that needed removing

Comment: which version you have added. Please add output of `pip freeze`

Answer (score 1):

pip install Flask==2.1.3

The following blog has all the fixes in detail:
https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-unbound-message

Comment: Link-only answers have risk of link going dead. Please consider providing summary/steps from link to solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

upgrade your Werkzeug dependencies will solve your issues

pip install Flask Werkzeug --upgrade

pip3 install Flask Werkzeug --upgrade

python -m pip install Flask Werkzeug --upgrade

python3 -m pip install Flask Werkzeug --upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are outdated versions of Flask/Werkzeug: `pip list --outdated` (replacing `pip` with `pip3` as needed)

If Flask/Werkzeug are listed, consider upgrading them: `pip install Flask Werkzeug --upgrade` (with the caveat that doing so may break packages and/or dependencies in your project)

Information taken [from here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-unbound-message) which was provided by an earlier response in this thread.

Answer (score -1):

This was the error i got app_ctx: AppContext = LocalProxy(  # type: ignore[assignment]
TypeError: LocalProxy.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unbound_message'

This how i solved after 5 hours of toiling

What I did on linux server

1. First I ran `pip3 uninstall flask` or `pip uninstall flask`
2. I am on ubuntu server so I went to

> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages

and deleted the Flask folder
3. I ran pip install -U 'flask<2.2.0' or pip3 install -U 'flask<2.2.0'
4. I went back to

> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/global.py

to check that
app_ctx: AppContext = LocalProxy() is what we have in 53

For local host

1. First I ran pip3 uninstall flask or pip uninstall flask
2. I ran `pip install -U 'flask<2.2.0'` or `pip3 install -U 'flask<2.2.0'`
3. That is all flask should be working fine now